# How to dismiss all instance of alarm dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using the following alarm dialog to display when my TCP connection is off by sending an intent to MainActivity and dismissing it when I receive the connection back.

```
 private void showAlarmDialog(){
    is_showing = true;
    alarmDialog = new AlarmDialog();
    alarmDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Alarm dialog");
}
```

The problem, when I try to reconnect, I create multiple instances of the alarm dialog. This dismisses `alarmDialog.dismiss()` only one of it. Still my dialog is visible, even though I get my connection back.

```
private void close(){
    alarmDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Is there anyway to close all and return to UI ?

Comment: Do you need all the instances in the first place, or could your problem be solved by making sure you only launch one alarm dialog?

Comment: No I just need only one instance to show and dismiss it.

Comment: I solved it by adding a simple boolean value. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: I was just drafting an answer based on your is_showing flag. You were probably not resetting it or checking it properly, as it seems to be there to prevent multiple instances of the dialog. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: yes man, I did the exact thing. It was right in front of my eyes. After reading your comment. suddenly i saw how stupid i was :)

Comment: sometimes all it takes is describing your problem to someone to realise what the solution actually is. Stepping away from your code or a second pair of eyes can help most of the times!

Comment: exactly :) Totally agreed ! cheers man